# Why does my query with named parameters return a blank result?

Tags: php, pdo, sql-injection

I am converting my MySQL code over to PDO to take advantage of prepared statements.  I was originally getting a fatal error as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663656/why-is-my-prepared-statement-giving-me-a-fatal-error/).  I had solved that issue, but it brought up more problems when trying to add parameters.

The code I am trying to get working is:

```
include ("foo/bar.php");

try {
     $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    }  
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
    }

    $mydate=date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-3 months"));

    $foo_query=$DBH->prepare("SELECT id, postdate, title, SUBSTRING_INDEX(body,' ',20) as preview_text, body FROM BarTable WHERE postdate = :postdate AND postdate > '$mydate' ORDER BY postdate DESC");
    $foo_query->execute( array('postdate' => $_REQUEST['postdate']) );

    $DBH=null;
```

In English, this is meant to read "*take the current date and set it back 3 months calling it $mydate, then select all of those fields (also taking the first 20 words of the body and calling it 'preview_text') from my table where the postdate is equal to the parameter postdate and where postdate is greater than $mydate*".

I am then displaying the results in the following (note this is now abridged):

```
$foo_query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while($r=$foo_query->fetch()) {
    echo $r["id"];
    echo $r["title"];
    echo date("d-M-Y",strtotime($r["postdate"]));
    echo nl2br ($r["preview_text"]); }
```

Now, while the SELECT query is written as:

```
("SELECT id, postdate, title, SUBSTRING_INDEX(body,' ',20) as preview_text, body FROM BarTable WHERE postdate > '$mydate' ORDER BY postdate DESC")
```

...it displays exactly what I need it to, but of course while this is prepared, it contains no parameters so only achieves 50% of the goal.

I was under the impression the way of preparing the statement that I outlined initially would be fine as per the tutorials and advice I have already been given.

I have tried to print my error and it brings up no error.  I manually sent the query as follows and get no returns.  Note I have tried the date strings in all manner of permutations:

```
("SELECT id, postdate, title, SUBSTRING_INDEX(body,' ',20) as preview_text, body FROM BarTable WHERE postdate = 20121001 AND postdate > 20120701 ORDER BY postdate DESC")
```

**EDIT: The above was pointed out as incorrect but I will keep it here for reference as this section is explained in the comments below.**

**EDIT: Manually sending the query now displays correctly when typing:**

```
("SELECT id, postdate, title, SUBSTRING_INDEX(body,' ',20) as preview_text, body FROM BarTable WHERE postdate = '2012-09-30 08:38:23' ORDER BY postdate DESC")
```

The query does not display at all when typing any of the following:

```
("SELECT id, postdate, title, SUBSTRING_INDEX(body,' ',20) as preview_text, body FROM BarTable WHERE postdate = :postdate ORDER BY postdate DESC")
("SELECT id, postdate, title, SUBSTRING_INDEX(body,' ',20) as preview_text, body FROM BarTable WHERE postdate = :postdate AND postdate > '$mydate' ORDER BY postdate DESC")
("SELECT id, postdate, title, SUBSTRING_INDEX(body,' ',20) as preview_text, body FROM BarTable WHERE postdate = '2012-09-30 08:38:23' AND postdate > '2012-07-01 00:01' ORDER BY postdate DESC")
```

I am thinking that I should bind the parameter in some way, but the tutorials I've read do not specifically say that I should always bind them - I'm unsure of how to proceed.

**EDIT : I have looked to bind the statement as follows with no success.  The query seemingly ignores the bind so the state of the query acts as all of the above permutations without binding:**

```
$foo_query->bindParam (
   ":postdate", strtotime ( $_REQUEST['postdate']), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$foo_query->execute();
```

What am I doing wrong, that isn't happening when I don't add parameters?  Should I be declaring the :postdate parameter somewhere other than in the SELECT query?

For the purposes of preventing SQL injection I would like to use named parameters as well as preparing the statement, but if I can't figure it out then I will just have to not used named parameters.

Comment: postdate = 20121001 AND postdate > 20120701 ?

Comment: yeah - in English it should read "The postdate is equal to 01-Oct-2012, and the postdate should be greater than 01-July-2012".  This complies with the way I was shown to write that statement - postdate = :postdate AND postdate > '$mydate'

Comment: Your missing the point, 20121001 is per definition greater then 20120701. The `AND` in your query has no meaning! Only records with the date 20121001 will be returned. Are there any?

Comment: See this is where I think the issue lies.  I have tried all manner of date permutations so dont read too heavily into the actual string.  Does it have to be in the format that I see in phpmyadmin for example?  Does AND not mean anything in SELECT queries?  I have used it before in MySQL and in queries elsewhere.

Comment: Date format for MySQL is YYYYMMDD. Think again .. You want something that is from 1 okt 2012 AND later then 1 july 2012. What is the result?

Comment: No I understand that now.  But bear in mind though that my original unprepared query returned the result, yet the prepared one does not.  Im not getting too hung up on my manual query as this has no bearing on what I will actually do other than testing for returned data - which the query does unprepared.

Comment: Sorry I realised that I did not answer a part of your question - yes there are records there from 01-Oct-2012, still the issue remains that The query returns no results with parameters.

Comment: I posted a 'answer', hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using parameter through a array, you are binding with the default parameter type `PDO::PARAM_STR`

Dependending on the datatype:

- The MySQL timestamp data-type: it's the same, you'll pass it as a string
- The PHP Unix timestamp, which is an integer: you'll pass it an int.

I suggest you change your code like this:

```
$foo_query=$DBH->prepare(
   "SELECT id, postdate, title, SUBSTRING_INDEX(body,' ',20) as preview_text, body 
    FROM BarTable WHERE postdate = :postdate 
    ORDER BY postdate DESC");
$foo_query->bindParam (
   ":postdate", strtotime ( $_REQUEST['postdate']), PDO::PARAM_INT); 
//                                                  ^^^ bind as integer
$foo_query->execute();
```

Comment: This is still not bringing up any queries for me.  I'm not receiving any errors however.  How does this tie in with the date I set with $mydate?

Comment: Other than replacing AND with OR (as per the other question...) then this worked.  Thanks for all the help.