# How do present my WHERE conditions to return rows correctly?

Tags: php, pdo

I am struggling to find out why my query is returning zero rows.  I have extensively tried to figure this out at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689103/why-does-my-query-with-named-parameters-return-a-blank-result) with no decent results.

The jist of it is:

```
    $mydate=date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-3 months"));

    $foo_query=$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM BarTable WHERE postdate = :postdate AND postdate > '$mydate' ORDER BY postdate DESC");
    $foo_query->execute( array('postdate' => $_REQUEST['postdate']) );
```

**EDIT : This query is supposed to say take the date, set it three months in the past, and call it $mydate.  Then take all fields from BarTable WHERE the postdate is greater than $mydate, then execute the query.**

It has just been pointed out to me that what I have said is that I'm selecting rows where the postdate is equal to 3 months ago and also greater than `$mydate`.

I don't understand how I'm saying this. `:postdate` is not equal to 3 months ago so `postdate = :postdate` can't be selecting rows where the postdate is equal to 3 months ago.

To display my rows correctly I was previously typing `WHERE postdate > '$mydate'`.

How can I type `postdate = :postdate AND postdate > '$mydate'` so that I am using a parameter and also making sure that data is selected based on being greater than `$mydate`?

Comment: Your `postdate` can't be equal to some date and be greater than some date. Do you mean to use `OR`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to query for? Rows more recent than three months, or rows on the date specified in `$_REQUEST['postdate']`, or both?

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? You want posts which are later than 3 months ago? Or do you want posts which were posted on :postdate??

Comment: There it is again: `postdate = :postdate AND postdate > '$mydate'` How can a date be equal to a date AND greater then a date?

Comment: @JvdBerg - the two dates he's comparing for are defined separately. `$mydate` is from strtotime, and postdate from `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: @andrewsi I have updated the question to explain the query in plain English (hopefully)

Comment: @JvdBerg :postdate is not the current date.  It is an attempt to assign a parameter to 'postdate'.

Comment: And is the field postdate a timestamp or a date field, that is important for the parameter binding?

Comment: I added a 'answer', hope it helps

Comment: @JvdBerg postdate is a timestamp based on the date of upload

Comment: So the the field in the database is op type `TIMESTAMP` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to bind the parameter for `postdate`. also, to get both critierias satisfied, `postdate  = :postdate and postdate > $mydate`, you need to use `OR` in your query.

```
$mydate=date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-3 months"));
$foo_query=$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM BarTable WHERE postdate = :postdate OR postdate > '$mydate' ORDER BY postdate DESC");
$foo->bindParam(':postdate', $_REQUEST['postdate'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$foo_query->execute();
```

OR similar to what you mentioned in your question, you missed the `:` when assigning the `:postdate`,

```
 $mydate=date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-3 months"));
 $foo_query=$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM BarTable WHERE postdate = :postdate OR postdate   '$mydate' ORDER BY postdate DESC");
 $foo_query->execute( array(':postdate' => $_REQUEST['postdate']) );
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the binding, but that is also an area that I'm unsure that I need to include.  Why would I use OR?  I want the criteria to satisfy both, not one or the other?

Comment: suppose `$mydate = '2012-07-03', and :postdate = '2012-08-05'`, when you say `postdate = :postdate AND postdate > '$mydate'`, it will only check for values when `postdate = '2012-08-05'`, as the `=` operator sets the value to be searched to '2012-08-05'. It will not pull records for say `postdate = '2012-08-10'`

Comment: if thats what you want, then keep the query as it is, with `AND`

Comment: Also, to use the operator `>` you need the date format as `'Ymd'` in this line `$mydate=date("Ymd",strtotime("-3 months"));` so as to compare integers.

Comment: When using OR in this way, is this query still considered parameterised?  Obviously SQL injection prevention is important, so by using OR will all results contain that parameter?  I sense yes?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly (Which I'm entirely not sure about), you want `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
$foo_query=$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM BarTable WHERE postdate = :postdate OR postdate > '$mydate' ORDER BY postdate DESC");
```

This way, you get BOTH the posts which were later than 3 months ago, and the posts which were posted on `:postdate`.

Comment: This may tie into a question I asked above.  Is OR appropriate for the query?  I want to satisfy both that postdate is equal to the parameter :postdate, and also that the postdate is greater than the date set in $mydate (which is three months ago)

Comment: @tomdot: If you want to satisfy both conditions, i.e. don't display a query even if it's requested (but too old), than you AND. if you want both, go with OR.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do parameter binding you could try this, assuming that your postdate is a **date field**:

```
$foo_query=$DBH->prepare("
   SELECT * FROM BarTable 
   WHERE postdate = :postdate AND postdate > '$mydate' ORDER BY postdate DESC");
$foo_query->bindParam(':postdate', $_REQUEST['postdate'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$foo_query->execute();
```

However, if your postdate is a **timestamp** it should look like this:

```
$foo_query=$DBH->prepare("
   SELECT * FROM BarTable 
   WHERE postdate = :postdate AND postdate > '$mydate' ORDER BY postdate DESC");
$foo_query->bindParam(':postdate', $_REQUEST['postdate'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$foo_query->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about whether the field is date or timestamp.  This will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend "BETWEEN":

```
$foo_query=$DBH->prepare(
  "SELECT * FROM BarTable 
  WHERE postdate between ':somedate' AND '$mydate' 
  ORDER BY postdate DESC");
```

Comment: This wont work because the query should eventually not show results older than the date set in $mydate, but show all other results